# How to draw a smart drag and drop polyline by python Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, drag-and-drop

I made a class to create a poly-line which is composed by the lines and can be  drag and drop. However there are two questions as following:

1. If there is a smart way to let the poly-line automatically bypass the object(such as a rectangle) when I move it?
2. If there is any smart way to just select one of the line and change its position but keep all lines connected?

'''

```
from tkinter import *

class polyline:
    def __init__(self,coords,canvas):
        self.lines_list = []
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.selected = False
        self.x_list,self.y_list = [],[]
        for i in range(len(coords)-1):
            self.lines_list.append(canvas.create_line(coords[i][0],coords[i][1], coords[i+1][0],coords[i+1][1]))
        self.get_diagonal_coords()
    def get_diagonal_coords(self):
        self.x_list,self.y_list = [],[]
        for i in self.lines_list:
            coord = self.canvas.coords(i)
            self.x_list.append(coord[0])
            self.x_list.append(coord[2])
            self.y_list.append(coord[1])
            self.y_list.append(coord[3])
        self.x_min = min(self.x_list)
        self.y_min = min(self.y_list)
        self.x_max = max(self.x_list)
        self.y_max = max(self.y_list)
        # print self.x_min,self.y_min
    def move(self,move_dis):
        self.get_diagonal_coords()
        if self.x_min+move_dis[0] > 10 and self.y_min+move_dis[1] > 10 and self.x_max +move_dis[0]< canvas.winfo_width()-10 and self.y_max +move_dis[1]<canvas.winfo_height()-10:
            for l in self.lines_list:
                self.canvas.move(l,move_dis[0],move_dis[1])
                # print self.x_list
    def goto(self,destination):
        self.get_diagonal_coords()
        move_dis = (destination[0]-self.x_min,destination[1]-self.y_min)
        self.move(move_dis)
        self.get_diagonal_coords()

    def select(self,coord):
        self.get_diagonal_coords()
        if coord[0]>self.x_min and coord[1]>self.y_min and coord[0]<self.x_max and coord[1]<self.y_max:
            self.selected = True
        return False


master = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(master, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()
# canvas.create_line(20,200,1,200)
global p
p = polyline([(10,200),(50,200),(50,300),(150,300),(150,360)],canvas)

def onclick_handler(event):
    global p,start
    start = (event.x-p.x_min, event.y-p.y_min)
    pass
    p.select((event.x, event.y))
   
def on_drag_motion(event):
    global p,start
    # print p.selected
    if p.selected:
        p.goto((event.x-start[0], event.y-start[1]))


def onrelease_handler(event):
    global p
    p.selected = False

canvas.bind("<Button-1>", onclick_handler)
canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", on_drag_motion)
canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", onrelease_handler)

master.mainloop()
```

'''

[Effect demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMOd0.gif)

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Here is an example for drag and drop a canvas item. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63093042/13629335

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import *

class draw_polyline:
    def __init__(self,canvas,vertical):
        self.lines_list = []
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.vertical = vertical
        self.click_num = 0
        pass

    def start_draw_line(self,event):
        x1,y1,x,y = event.x,event.y,event.x,event.y
        if self.click_num  == 0:
            if self.vertical:
                self.lines_list.append(self.canvas.create_line(x1,y1,x1,y))
            else:
                self.lines_list.append(self.canvas.create_line(x1,y1,x,y1))

        else:
            l = self.lines_list[self.click_num-1]
            coords = self.canvas.coords(l)
            if self.vertical:
                self.lines_list.append(self.canvas.create_line(coords[2],coords[3],coords[2],y+5))
            else:
                self.lines_list.append(self.canvas.create_line(coords[2],coords[3],x+5,coords[3]))

        canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.move_and_draw)
        canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.onrelease_handler)

    def onrelease_handler(self,event):
        self.vertical = not self.vertical
        self.click_num+=1

    def in_the_range(self,l,coord):
        coords = self.canvas.coords(l)
        x_min,x_max = min(coords[0],coords[2]),max(coords[0],coords[2])
        y_min,y_max = min(coords[1],coords[3]),max(coords[1],coords[3])
        x_in_range = coord[0]>x_min-3 and coord[0]<x_max+3
        y_in_range = coord[1]>y_min-3 and coord[1]<y_max+3
        return x_in_range and y_in_range

    def move_and_draw(self,event):
        if len(self.lines_list)>0:
            l = self.lines_list[self.click_num]
            coords = self.canvas.coords(l)
            x1,y1,x,y = coords[0],coords[1],event.x,event.y
            if self.vertical:
                if y-y1<5:
                    y = int(y+5*abs(y-y1)/((y-y1)+1e-9))
                self.canvas.coords(l,x1,y1,x1,y)
            else:
                if x-x1<5:
                    x = int(x+5*abs(x-x1)/((x-x1)+1e-9))
        
                self.canvas.coords(l,x1,y1,x,y1)
            
    def onclick_handler(self,event):
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.start_draw_line)
    def start_draw(self):
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.start_draw_line)



master = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(master, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()
p =  draw_polyline(canvas = canvas,vertical=True)
p.start_draw()
master.mainloop()
```